# Reason for applying energy conservation and balancing force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, spring

I've this question

[image]

When asked I was told that we will balance force for $2m$ object

i.e., $(2\mu)2mg=Kx$

And we will conserve energy for $m$ mass

i.e., $Fx=\frac{1}{2}kx^2+\mu mgx$

Both the blocks are attached to the same spring so why is it wrong to balance forces for both the masses. I want to know why can't we do vice versa rather how does the solution work

I am not asking for calculations or answer to a homework question but asking for a concept involved.

Comment: I was writing an answer to your egg question when the question was deleted, so I lost it. Have a look here https://greekreporter.com/2021/05/01/why-greeks-crack-red-eggs-on-easter/ . The reason eggs break is 1) air bubbles which are bigger the older the egg, 2) thickness of skin 3) previous undetected  cracks

Comment: @annav thank you so much I was getting downvotes so I closed it

Answer (score 0):

The question specifically says that $F$ is the minimum force needed to move the $2m$ mass. As the spring extends by a length $x_{\circ}$, the smaller mass $m$ has an acceleration due to the net force provided $F$, friction and spring force.

As no data about the acceleration is provided in the question we cannot balance any force equation for mass $m$ without knowing its acceleration.